# Archive data row to another tab while data is imported through importrange (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

My script archives a row from "2019-2020" to "Fully Invoiced" tab. But, the row doesn't disappear from the "2019-2020" tab. I think this is because the data is imported from another spreadsheet through a `importrange` function. I would like this row to disappear.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // target sheet of move to named Paid
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 2 or B
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  // Message box when archiving a project
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
    if((s.getName() == "2019-2020")&& r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {   
    var response = Browser.msgBox('Make sure the project has been fully invoiced before archiving it. Are you sure to continue?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
      Logger.log(response);
  if (response == "yes") {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fully Invoiced");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
  }

  // Unarchive a project from Fully Invoiced tab to 2019-2020 tab
  else if(s.getName() == "Fully Invoiced" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("2019-2020");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);   
}
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is it important for you to preserve the importrange formula in the sheet, or would it be possible to make the imported values static (not update when the source range updates)?

Comment: It is important to update data from the source range unfortunately... So I was thinking maybe creating a script that copy past value (static) from the importrange... The imported data is ordered by ascending (a creation date), that means that normally, there won't be a row placed between past rows; there are reported at the end of the table. But this is a rudimental solution... What do you think? Thank you for your help

Comment: Making a static copy of the imported data the way you describe would be a possible solution. Otherwise, what is your exact importrange formula? Maybe you can import per row instead of the whole sheet and replace the rows you don't expect to change anymore through static values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to delete the entry from the source file. `IMPORTRANGE()` will always pull in the range you request in view only mode, i.e. you can not change values. If you want to change / remove values, then you need to do that in the source file.

- Source File = The file which contains the original data
- Working File = The file which uses IMPORTRANGE to get data from the Source File